# Does any know how to get around viewDidAppear not being triggered when exiting from a UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl segue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, viewdidappear

Does any know how to get around `viewDidAppear` not being hit when exiting from a `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` segue?

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelector:(id)sender
{

    // creating object for title screen
    UIStoryboard *storySelection =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    // creating object for profile view
    selectorViewController = [storySelection instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Verse Selector"];

    // setting the transition style
    selectorViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

    // performing the segue
    [self presentViewController:selectorViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // testing for a return from segue
    if (selectorViewController != nil)
    {
        // getting the chosen values from the instance
        chosenBook = selectorViewController.chosenBook;

        // setting instance to nil for garbage collection
        selectorViewController = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It looks like the best route is to implement a custom delegate protocol which notifies the presenting view controller that the presented view controller is being dismissed.

Comment: I placed the function in the controller that started the curl transition and that function was not triggered upon return to that controller.

Comment: It really should be....  Did you try putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the function to see if it is ever called?

Comment: yup, breakpoint confirms that upon exit from the 'curl' transition `- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` is not fired.  It's quite possible that I'm doing something stupid.  Do I call the dismissal the same way in the view being dismissed?  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: right now I'm cheating by passing the data back through a singleton

Comment: You should just call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`...

Comment: that's what I'm doing.  `viewDidAppear` is called when I use any other transition than curl, but no matter what transition I use it never calls the `-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated` override.  I copied the code you posted right into the view controller that is performing the segue.

Comment: Yeah, `viewDidAppear` isn't called with this transition, but I'm not sure why the other one isn't working for your...  Sorry!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25063/discussion-between-grymjack-and-lnafziger)

Comment: thanks to lnafziger in helping to implement a custom dismissal protocol.  We were not able to figure out why `(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` wouldn't fire.  If anyone has any further thoughts on that, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would to be to set your initial view controller as a delegate to your modally presented view controller. Before presenting the view controller:

```
selectedViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:selectorViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, in the modal view controller, in whichever method dismisses the modal presentation, directly call viewDidAppear: on the original view controller.

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate viewDidAppear:NO];
    [self.delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I get the following error:  `Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'selectorViewController'`

Comment: am I misunderstanding how the delegated should be implemented?

Comment: thanks, I was helped by lnafziger in how to implement a custom delegate protocol.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer.